# Two definitions of covariance of a multivariate distribution seem to give different answers

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, covariance

The formal definition of the covariance between two random variables $X$ and $Y$ is
$$\mathrm{cov}(X, Y)=\big\langle\big(X-\langle X\rangle\big)\big(Y-\langle Y\rangle\big)\big\rangle,$$
whereas the usual shortcut, easily proven to be equivalent, is
$$\mathrm{cov}(X, Y)=\langle XY\rangle - \langle X\rangle\langle Y\rangle.$$
(Notational note: I use $\langle X\rangle$ to denote the expectation value of the random variable $X$.)

As an example, consider the joint probability density function given by
$$f(x,y)=\mathrm{Pr}[X{\approx}x; Y{\approx}y]=\cases{{kx\textrm{ on the unit square}}\\{0\textrm{ otherwise},}}$$ where $k$ is a constant.

I now compute some expectation values:

$$\langle X\rangle=\int_0^1\int_0^1 x\, f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y = \frac13 k.$$
$$\langle Y\rangle=\int_0^1\int_0^1 y\, f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y = \frac14 k.$$
$$\langle XY\rangle=\int_0^1\int_0^1 xy\, f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y = \frac16 k.$$

Thus, computing $\mathrm{cov}(X, Y)$ by the formal definition, I get
$$\begin{align}\mathrm{cov}(X, Y)&=\big\langle\big(X-\langle X\rangle\big)\big(Y-\langle Y\rangle\big)\big\rangle\\&=\int_0^1\int_0^1\big(x-\tfrac13k\big)\big(y-\tfrac14k\big)\,f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\\&=\frac{k}{24}(k-2)^2.\end{align}$$

But using the shortcut definition, I instead get
$$\mathrm{cov}(X, Y)=\langle XY\rangle - \langle X\rangle\langle Y\rangle = \frac16 k-\frac{1}{12} k^2.$$

Why do I get two different answers? Which solution is right, and what did I do wrong in the other one?

Comment: Note that $k = 2$ due to normalisation. Now both your answers are $0$.

Answer (score 2):

All of your integrations seem to be correct, but there are several difficulties here. All worth straightening out, before they cause you difficulties later.

First, because you are
using integrals (no sums) you must have a bivariate *continuous*
density function on the unit square. In that case, you *cannot* correctly
write $f(x,y) = P(X=x, Y=y).$

Second, in order for $f(x,y) = kx$ to integrate to $1$ over the
unit square, you must have $k = 2.$ (That is what the Comment means by
'normalization'.) Also, it is
clear that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, so the covariance is $0.$
'Clearly independent' because $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = (2x)(1) = f_X(x)f_Y(y),$
for $0 < x < 1$ and $0 < y < 1.$ 
This means that $X \sim Beta(2,1)$ and $Y \sim Unif(0,1),$ independently.

Third, you have $E(X) = 2/3,\,$ $E(Y) = 1/2),\,$ and $E(XY) = 1/3.$

Then, as in the Comment by @stochasticboy321, $E[(X = E(X))(Y = E(Y))] = 0$
and also $E(XY) - E(X)E(Y) = 0.$

---

Finally, I think this is not a particularly good example because the
covariance is $0.$ Perhaps a better example is to have the joint density
function be defined as $k$ on the triangle with vertices at the origin,
$(1,1)$ and $(0.1).$

Obviously *not* independent because $P(X > .5) > 0$ and $P(Y < .5) > 0,$
while $P(X > .5, Y < .5) = 0.$

Maybe you can try that for practice. You can begin
by showing that $k = 2$ (here also). Take care with the limits on the
integrals, integrating over a triangle.

I simulated this example in R by generating a million points uniformly at random
in the unit square, and then trowing away the ones for which $X > Y.$
Then *approximate* quantities are found in the simulation:  $E(X) \approx .33,$
$E(Y) \approx .67,$  and $Cov(X,Y) \approx .028$ (two ways). Also (not shown), $E(XY) \approx .25.$ You can use
these approximate answers to check your exact ones, if you choose to try
the extra problem.

```
 m = 10^6;  x = runif(10^6);  y = runif(10^6)
 acc = x < y;  x = x[acc];  y = y[acc]  # keep relevant points
 mean(x);  mean(y);  cov(x,y)
 ## 0.3330813
 ## 0.6665181
 ## 0.02760107
 mean(x*y) - mean(x)*mean(y)
 ## 0.02760101
```

A plot of the first 30,000 of the accepted points illustrates the uniform distribution
over the indicated triangle.

[image]

Comment: Re: Continuous distribution: Thanks. I knew that, but I realized just before posting that my question didn't define lowercase *x* and *y*, so I hastily threw that in there without thinking about it hard enough. •
Re: Normalization: Obviously this was the important piece I was missing from my attempted solution. Thanks to you and to @stochasticboy321 for pointing it out. •
Re: "Clearly independent": What is the general statement here? You have pointed out that *X* and *Y* must be independent because the joint distribution function is separable, but your next example clearly demonstrates that…

Comment: …the shape of the distribution's domain of support is also relevant. Is there a general statement to be made here? "If a joint distribution function is separable and has a rectangular domain of support, its associated random variables are independent?" Or something? Can I do better?

Comment: Technically each factor needs to have an identity function that depends on the domain of support. Rectangular region makes that easier.